# angularjs - ng-repeat inside ng-included partial not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

In my parent page I include a partial using ng-include. Within that partial I use a ng-repeat to echo out form elements.

As you can see, the array for ng-repeat has 4 items (elements.length), but for whatever reason, angularjs skips ng-repeat completely. As if the directive is disabled.

I use this exact same setup (ng-include a partial that has ng-repeat) in other areas of my app without any problems. For the life of me I can't figure out why this one just skips ng-repeat.

parent page:

```
<div ng-include src="'/views/form/partial.html'"></div>
```

partial.html

```
    <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="{{form.url}}{{form.hash}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="h" value="{{form.hash}}" />
    <p>Elements: {{elements.length}}</p>
<pre>{{elements|json}}</pre>
    <div ng-repeat="element in elements">
        <label for="{{element.variable}}">{{element.display}}</label>
        <input type="input" id="{{element.variable}}" name="{{element.variable}}" value="" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="{{form.submit_text}}" />
</form>
```

What is rendered in the partial:

```
    <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://weebsite.com/h/eb58f4450026eae5815cbf4742cb27cd">
    <input type="hidden" name="h" value="eb58f4450026eae5815cbf4742cb27cd" />
    <p>Elements: 4</p>
<pre>[
  {
    "variable": "email",
    "mandatory": true,
    "display": "Email",
    "hidden": false
  },
  {
    "variable": "first_name",
    "mandatory": false,
    "display": "First Name",
    "hidden": false
  },
  {
    "variable": "last_name",
    "mandatory": false,
    "display": "Last Name",
    "hidden": false
  },
  {
    "variable": "new_field_3335",
    "mandatory": false,
    "display": "New Field",
    "hidden": false
  }
]</pre>
    <div ng-repeat="element in elements">
        <label for=""></label>
        <input type="input" id="" name="" value="" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="click me now" />
    </form>
```

Comment: My guess is `elements` structure is not what you think it is. Simple check in view is `<pre>{{elements|json}}</pre>`. Show data sample and create a demo in plunker that reproduces this

Comment: added the <pre> as you suggest, results are above. Since I have this working in other places I figure plunker will also work. Hoping someone will come along with "oh, when ng-repeat doesn't work in a ng-include, it's because...." If this question goes to tomorrow I'll take the time to make a plunker.

Comment: should work fine...that `<pre>` is inside ng-include . So scope is fine and so is the structure

Comment: have you tried in a second browser?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, ng-repeat fails inside a `<textarea>`, while other variable substitution works as expected.

The partial.html is inside a `<textarea>`. Once I removed it from the `<textarea>`, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code snippet of your code: Only the problem was that you have to pass all varialbes and elements json from controller.
Just make sure is that angular js load properly.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[])
                   .controller("myController", function ($scope){
    var elements = [
  {
    "variable": "email",
    "mandatory": true,
    "display": "Email",
    "hidden": false
  },
  {
    "variable": "first_name",
    "mandatory": false,
    "display": "First Name",
    "hidden": false
  },
  {
    "variable": "last_name",
    "mandatory": false,
    "display": "Last Name",
    "hidden": false
  },
  {
    "variable": "new_field_3335",
    "mandatory": false,
    "display": "New Field",
    "hidden": false
  }
]
    $scope.elements = elements;
 $scope.form = {
 "hash":"eb58f4450026eae5815cbf4742cb27cd", "submit_text":"submit", "url":"http://weebsite.com/h/"
 };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myModule">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="app1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="myController">
               <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://weebsite.com/h/">
    <input type="hidden" name="h" value="{{form.hash}}" />
    

    <div ng-repeat="element in elements">
        <label for="{{element.variable}}">{{element.display}}</label>
        <input type="input" id="{{element.variable}}" name="{{element.variable}}" value="" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="{{form.submit_text}}" />
</form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with passing all the variables from the controller. I clearly demonstrated the variables were all there by showing the length of the array. The ng-repeat was wrapped in a textarea, and within textareas ng-repeat isn't executed.